# Form Collecting Spreadsheet to Calendar issue

Tags: google-apps-script

Im trying to add information from a form-collecting spreadsheet to a calendar. i have the following function written:

```
function addEvents(){
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
 var lr = ss.getLastRow();
 var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("vaadcatering@gmail.com");

 var data = ss.getRange("A2:D" + lr).getValues();

 for(var i = 0;i<data.length;i++){

cal.createEvent.(data[i][0], data[i][1], data[i][2], {location:data[i][3]});

  }

}
```

When I run the script however, it tells me:
TypeError: function createEvent() {/* */} is not an XML object. (line 43, file "checklist to calendar")

[line 43 being the cal.creatEvent etc. line]

Any suggestions on how i could fix this??

Thanks so much

ps- if it helps the names of the columns A-D are:
Name of Caterer-Start Date-End Date-Location/address

Comment: You have a '.' after createEvent, hence the error. Also, the 'createEvent()' method doesn't seem to have this specific method signature. All of your parameters are strings - none of the documented descriptions of this method can accept 4 strings. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/

Comment: Is there a way I can incorporate all of the start and end dates without them being strings?